# How to find London Session starting H1 Candle High and Low?

Tags: mql4, mt4

```
if(Hour()==9)//How can I find the the High and Low of H1 candle of starting London session?
{

}
```

When the H1 Candle ends in which London session started, what is the best way to find H1 candle High, Low, Open and Close?
Infact London session starts inside this H1 candle.